# Google Cloud Storage bucket disappeared from GCP project but still in use somehow

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have had this problem for days, so I decided to post here hoping for a little help.I am not a GCP expert. :D
So last year i created a static website for one of my friends. She bought a G Suite package for her business so i made a website, hosted on the google platform using Cloud Storage.
I made a project in GCP, created a bucket in it which i named [www.domainname.hu](http://www.domainname.hu) (example name), uploaded the static website. In terms of DNS management i use Cloudflare. I have an A record with the root domain domainname.hu (again, example name) and a CNAME record named www pointing to c.storage.googleapis.com, along with some MX records. Everything worked fine.

Some additional info:

- i picked default settings during bucket creation wizard
- i did not touch bucket lifecycle
- i made the bucket public for the internet by adding allUsers Storage Object Viewer permission

Earlier this week we wanted to update the website with some new content, so i logged in into GCP.
The project was empty, the bucket with the website in it disappeared.

So i just need to create a new bucket with the same name and upload the website again right? Wrong  :DD

When i tried to create a new one with the same name an error message came up : " That bucket name is taken. Try another. " Interesting...

As far as i know your bucket name must match your domain name so google can point the requests to your bucket in the cloud. Obviously, the bucket name [www.domainname.hu](http://www.domainname.hu) that i created is in use somewhere in the cloud. Not by me, because it disappeared from my project. Now i can't make any updates to the website.

So i'm confused, why did the bucket disappeared from my project?

Why can't i create a new bucket with the same name?

Why is the bucket name still in use after it disappeared from the project?

Sorry for my bad english and thank you in advance for any help or ideas.

Comment: 1) Look in the Cloud Logging audit logs and review what happed to the bucket. 2) Did the customer have a billing problem that was ignored? 3) Do you have more than one project? Make sure you are looking in the correct one.

Comment: It smells like a wrong project location. Remember, the project name can be change, not the project ID, have a look on that. In addition, if you user account has access to all project, try a `gsutil ls` to list all the accessible bucket by your user, you should see it in the list.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, i have 1 project on that specific account. Everything was paid off so there are no billing issues. I checked the logs also but that was Chinese to me :D I also tried listing all the buckets in that project, found 0 buckets. Eventually I got tired. But since I don't know what happened and I don't want it to happen again, I moved the whole website to Aws. Now everything works again

Comment: For future reference, if this happens to anyone in the future, you should check if the bucket operations and storage is still being charged. If so, raise a support ticket with GCP's billing team (you're being charged for a resource you don't have access to). They might be able to investigate a little bit more: https://cloud.google.com/support/billing